# MVC Bootstrap datetimepick not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed the Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker by Eondasdan into my MVC project.

In BundleConfig.cs

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datepicker").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datepicker").Include(
                  "~/Content/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.less",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less"));
```

In _Layout.cshtml

I added this to the top

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/datepicker")
```

And this to the bottom

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foolproof")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datepicker")
```

The cshtml has this

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewMeeting.EndTime, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewMeeting.EndTime, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

However see screenshot, I don't think my datetimepicker is rendered correctly. I.e the mouse pointer is not shown instead it is a normal text cursor. The time icon is left aligned and also the currently selected date is not shown etc. Any ideas?

Screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/wamg3p43b/

Comment: check this article http://www.brendanforster.com/blog/yet-another-implement-less-in-aspnetmvc-post.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I switched to the CSS version of the bootstrap datetimepicker using NuGet and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to add the actual CSS files rather than the LESS files

Replace

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datepicker").Include(
                  "~/Content/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.less",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less"));
```

with

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datepicker").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"));
```

Comment: There is only less files installed by nuget as far as I can see.